# Using numpy.einsum for tensor dot of slices

Tags: python, numpy, tensor

I have an array of shape `N, j, j` and another of shape `M, j, j`. I want to calculate their tensor dot to eventually have a matrix where the `i,j` entry is `np.tensordot(arr1[i, :, :], arr2[j, :, :])`
I've tried looping but it is ridiculously slow, I've read about `np.einsum` but unfortunately cannot figure it out no matter how much I read.
My most recent attempt;
`np.einsum('ilk,ium->lu', arr1, arr2)`
But I keep getting errors that the shapes can't be broadcasted. Would appreciate any pointers, thanks!

example code:

```
  arr1 = np.zeros((5, 2, 2))
  arr2 = np.zeros((4, 2, 2))
  arr2[1,:,:][1,1] = 2
  arr1[1,:,:][1,1] = 3
  np.tensordot(arr1[1,:,:], arr2[1,:,:])
```

in this case, the tensor dot would give me 6. That is what I am interested in, for each `i,j`.

Comment: Could you post a sample code that demonstrates the problem ?

Comment: Since N and M are different, the first indices have to be different.  `ilk,jkm->ijlm', with 'dot' summing on the shared 'k' dimension.  Since the last 2 dimensions are the same, the index order can be different, but I'm assuming you want to usual "last of the first, 2nd to the last of second' 'dot'.  Note that I keep both 'i' and 'j'

Comment: @paisanco Edited with a toy example

Comment: `tensordot` with 2d arrays (and not axis values) is the regular `dot`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for your example, I modified it to be ilk,jkm->ij as I want the output to be 2d matrix. Now I get `iterator is too big` warning, did I do something wrong?

Comment: OK, I'm wrong, that `tensordot` is equivalent to 'kl,kl', summing on both of the last 2 dimensions.  'ikl,jkl->ij'   (default is axis=2, double contraction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [41]: x=np.arange(2*3*3).reshape(2,3,3)
In [42]: y=np.arange(4*3*3).reshape(4,3,3)
```

double contraction on the last 2 dim:

```
In [43]: np.einsum('ikl,jkl->ij',x,y)
Out[43]: 
array([[ 204,  528,  852, 1176],
       [ 528, 1581, 2634, 3687]])
```

test one value:

```
In [44]: np.tensordot(x[0],y[0])
Out[44]: array(204)
```

Same thing dot (and extra dimension)

```
In [47]: np.dot(x.reshape(-1,9),y.reshape(-1,9,1))
Out[47]: 
array([[[ 204],
        [ 528],
        [ 852],
        [1176]],

       [[ 528],
        [1581],
        [2634],
        [3687]]])
```

`np.tensordot` with the various axis options can be a bit tricky to use.  One way or other it reshapes and transposes the arrays so it can call `np.dot`.  Then it may do some further manipulation.

Or using broadcasting and multiaxis sum:

```
In [48]: (x[:,None,:,:]*y[None,:,:,:]).sum(axis=(2,3))
Out[48]: 
array([[ 204,  528,  852, 1176],
       [ 528, 1581, 2634, 3687]])
```

and a non-loop tensordot:

```
In [50]: np.tensordot(x,y,axes=((1,2),(1,2)))
Out[50]: 
array([[ 204,  528,  852, 1176],
       [ 528, 1581, 2634, 3687]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For my understanding, `'ikl,jkl->ij` iterates over the first axis, and multiplies the other two?

Comment: I added a multiply and sum equivalent.  and a full tensordot.